# How to use token as a filter value in views

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to use tokens in views filter values. For example, if I have text field 'my_custom_text' I would like to have a filter that would allow me to use 'Is equal to' operator and a token value instead of hardcoded string.

Note that I can't use contextual filters because I have few filters that needs to be ORed.

Is there a module for that, or do I have to code that myself from ground up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I've came up with eventually.

1. I did not want to use `global php filter` because it only limits the results that are already loaded from the DB. In my case this would mean loading 1000 rows just to display 2 of them. Not too wise I'd say.
2. I did not want to use `hook_views_query_alter` as this would mean that I'd have to dig into the code every time someone wants to change or create a view.

I ended up writing my own views handler that extends one of the exiting. I've also used `hook_field_views_data_alter` to hook up my handler instead of default.

This solution works quite nice. Custom handler is very robust solution and quite simple to implement... once you know how to do it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use Contextual Filters instead of Filter Criteria.

In Drupal 8, at the time of writing this, you also have to install the [views_argument_token](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_argument_token) module.

When adding a contextual filter, at the pop up window, select "Provide default value" option. From there on the remaining settings should be intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_views_query_alter` to done your job,

implement this hook in your custom module and with if statement restrict to your views name and edit views query,

Comment: That I'm aware of. I was rather looking for some robust existing solution. It's weird that it isn't possible to use tokens or at least PHP code to obtain filter value. After all views is one of the most popular modules.

Comment: yes, you can also use `cutom_php`  module and add `php GLOBAL` filter , and provide what you want

Comment: I don't want to use `GLOBAL` filter. I only want to provide custom PHP (or token) for the string filter value. This is for existing field.

Comment: I know, bu using `global php filter` you can add criteria on other field, I used this method sometimes and worked

Comment: unfortunately 'global' filter is kind a hack, not a real solution. It is used to filter data that is already loaded from the DB. This is useless if the returned result set is huge. And this is my case - the filter I want to implement will significantly limit number of rows returned, probably from approximately 1000 to just few. It would be really unwise to load 1000 rows from DB just to display only few of them :)

Comment: @SiliconMind , you also dont want use `hook_viwes_query_alter` ?

Comment: no I do not want to use hook_views_query_alter as this would require me to dig in the code every time someone wants to change or create a view. I ended up writing my own views handler that extends one of the exiting. Also used `hook_field_views_data_alter` hook up my handler instead of default. Works quite nice but I'm still curious if there is really no support for tokens in filter views.

Answer (score -1):

Would the [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module be helpful? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is a very simple module to make token values available as an input filter.
>
> The module now supports native tokens (e.g. [site:name]) and all global tokens by default. It even allows some contextual tokens like node or user to be replaced, but currently does not encourage users to use them in the filter help text.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: tokens cannot be used in views by design